# IfFileExists and filecontents causes an error

Tags: external-files

I would like to use the `filecontents` environment in my document. I get a warning

```
LaTeX Warning: File `test.txt' already exists on the system. 
Not generating it from this source.
```

If I run multiple passes of `pdfLaTeX` on the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
  Hello World
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
  \input{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```

The warning is obvious, the first pass creates the file, so the subsequent passes cause the warning. I thought I would be able to get rid of the warning with `IfFileExists`. The problem is that

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{\jobname.txt}{}{
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
    Hello World
  \end{filecontents}
}
\begin{document}
  \input{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```

Gives me an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

on the first pass and subsequent passes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The message is innocuous.

Comment: @egreg I understand that, but I thought I could easily avoid the error. I am more curious why IfFileExists causes the error.

Comment: The error is not from `\IfFileExist` directly; LaTeX enters a special state when doing `filecontents` and this makes it unhappy if the environment is in that position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do with this trick that avoids putting the `filecontents` environment inside the braces, which is the cause of the error:

```
\begingroup\newif\ifmy
\IfFileExists{\jobname.txt}{}{\mytrue}
\ifmy
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
  Hello World
\end{filecontents}
\fi\endgroup
```

Comment: `\ifv@`, like many other kernel booleans, isn't used by the filecontents environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know if I ever would have figured out, on my own, that adding the `filecontents` environment to a group causes problems. How did you know when LaTeX is in a "special" state?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub LaTeX is in such a special state because it may have to write out the file, so it does some tricks with the line terminator.

Answer (score 12):

This may not be entirely what you're after since your question was more about "how to" rather than "just get it done". However, in the question of interest, here one way of overwriting an existing file and not worrying about the overwrite warning issued by LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{silence}% http://ctan.org/pkg/silence
\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}% Remove LaTeX warnings starting with "Overwriting file"
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
  Hello World
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \input{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}​
```

The [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) provides `filecontents*` which overwrites a file if it already exists. The [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) gobbles warnings from LaTeX starting with "Overwriting file" via

```
\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}
```

The writing, even though its performed using `filecontents`, still is a LaTeX-related warning.

Comment: Werner, that’s only partly true: The `filecontents` package itself is responsible for the opportunity of overwriting existing files. The `filecontents*` environment does not print out the internal preamble which is prepended if one uses the environment `filecontents`.

Comment: @Speravir: This is true, although the "internal preamble" consists only of comments.

Comment: While not exactly what I was looking for, the `silence` package seems handy for when you know you are going to get warnings that you do not care about..